# How to collapse numbers with same identifier but different date, but preserve the date of first observation for each identifier

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that can be simplified in the following format:

```
clear
input str9 Date ID VarA VarB
"12jan2010" 5 21 42
"12jan2010" 6 47 21
"15jan2010" 10 7 68
"17jan2010" 6 -5 -3
"19jan2010" 6 -1 -1
end
```

In the dataset, there is Date, ID, VarA, and VarB. Each ID represents a unique set of transactions. I want to `collapse (sum) VarA VarB, by(Date)` in Stata. However, I want to keep the date of the first observation for each ID number.

Essentially, I want the above dataset to become the following:

```
+--------------------------------+
|    Date     ID   Var1   Var2   |
|--------------------------------|
| 12jan2010    5     21     42   |
| 12jan2010    6     41     17   |
| 15jan2010    10     7     68   |
+--------------------------------+
```

12jan2010 17jan2010 and 19jan2010 have the same ID, so I want to `collapse (sum) Var1 Var2` for these three observations. I want to keep the date 12jan2010 because it is the date for the first observation. The other two observations are dropped.

I know it might be possible to collapse by ID first and then merge with the original dataset and then subset. I was wondering if there is an easier way to make this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collapse` allows you to calculate a variety of statistics, so you can convert your string date into a numerical date, then take the minimum of the numerical date to get the first occurrence.

```
clear
input str9 Date ID VarA VarB
"12jan2010" 5 21 42
"12jan2010" 6 47 21
"15jan2010" 10 7 68
"17jan2010" 6 -5 -3
"19jan2010" 6 -1 -1
end

gen Date2 = date(Date, "DMY")
format Date2 %td
collapse (sum) VarA VarB (min) Date2 , by(ID)
order Date2, first
li
```

yielding

```
     +------------------------------+
     |     Date2   ID   VarA   VarB |
     |------------------------------|
  1. | 12jan2010    5     21     42 |
  2. | 12jan2010    6     41     17 |
  3. | 15jan2010   10      7     68 |
     +------------------------------+
```

---

In response to the comment: You can generate the formatted date for only observations where `VarA` is > 0 (and not missing). (Assuming that, per your comment, `VarA` & `VarB` always have the same sign.)

```
// now assume ID 6 has an earliest date of 17jan2005 (obs.4)
// but you want to return your 'first date' as the 
// first date where varA & varB are both positive
clear
input str9 Date ID VarA VarB
"12jan2010" 5 21 42
"12jan2010" 6 47 21
"15jan2010" 10 7 68
"17jan2005" 6 -5 -3
"19jan2010" 6 -1 -1
end

gen Date2 = date(Date, "DMY") if VarA > 0 & !missing(VarA)
format Date2 %td
collapse (sum) VarA VarB (min) Date2 , by(ID)
order Date2, first
li
```

yielding

```
     +------------------------------+
     |     Date2   ID   VarA   VarB |
     |------------------------------|
  1. | 12jan2010    5     21     42 |
  2. | 12jan2010    6     41     17 |
  3. | 15jan2010   10      7     68 |
     +------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question. What if the first observation is not always positive? For example, for one ID number, there first observation is with negative VarA and VarB, and I want to get the date that has the positive VarA and VarB. Assuming that VarA and VarB always have the same sign, and for each ID, there can be only one observation that has positive VarA and VarB.Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer for this additional criterion.